# Static AND moving?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I want a node to be static. So, that it is not affected by `gravity` and or `collision`. But, I also want it to move, is that possible? 
If I set `name.physicsbody.dynamic` to no it is not possible to apply a force or an impulse. I also tried to do it by an action - also failed - any ideas?

Comment: What programming language? What context or IDE? Is this maybe a question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Objective C and I used SpriteKit, I program a Jump'N'Run game and want to create a kind of platform which is static but still moves towards the player. I think it is the easiest way if the background and all the objects move and the player just pretends to. I hope I answered your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move a static physics body by setting the node's position manually or moving it with a move action should also work. But collision behavior may not be what you expect.

The alternative is to create a dynamic body with affectedByGravity set to NO and a collisionBitMask set to 0. You can move it with forces but it won't collide with anything (unless you add that category to the collisionBitMask).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I solved the problem by changing its position manually, guess it is not the dressiest solution, but it works! Thanks a lot! (Also tried to move it with a move action, but it didn't move somehow, probably has to be dynamic to work)

Comment: Edit: Nevermind it also works with a move action! I don't know why it didn't work this morning.